# Rails 5: How to refactor this controller code to the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I have the following code in my controller:

```
class VocabsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login, except: [:index, :quiz, :answer, :result]

...
def quiz
  #Initiate score session
  session[:score] ||= 0
  #Initiate session to hold questions already asked
  session[:already_asked] ||= []
  #Total score
  session[:amount_questions] = Vocab.all.length

  #Get list of words that hasn't been asked before
  @left_words = Vocab.all.where.not(id: session[:already_asked])

  #Questions remaining
  @questions_remaining = @left_words.length - 4

  #Pick four words from leftover words list
  @four = @left_words.shuffle.take(4)

  #Create question variable if there are enough words left in list
  if @left_words.length >= 4
    @question = @four.first.word
  else
    redirect_to result_path
  end

  #save score to user database if all questions done and logged in
  if @questions_remaining == 0
    high_score = Score.new
    high_score.user_id = session[:user_id]
    high_score.score = session[:score] /  session[:amount_questions].to_f
    high_score.save
    redirect_to result_path
  end
end

def answer
  #Keep score and question id's already asked
  if params[:answer] == params[:orig]
    session[:score] += 1
    session[:already_asked] << params[:answer].to_i
    flash[:notice] = "You got it right!"
    redirect_to quiz_path
  else
    session[:already_asked] << params[:orig].to_i
    flash[:notice] = "Sorry, wrong answer!"
    redirect_to quiz_path
  end
end
```

And I have the following model:

```
class Vocab < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :word, :definition, presence: true
end
```

I am trying to learn to adhere to the skinny controllers fat models paradigm, but since Rails doesn't let session variables pass to the model, how would I refactor this to the model?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, and should be moved to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to follow fat models skinny controllers in this case would be to create a model for the 'Quiz' itself then 'Quiz' would track the 'Vocab' questions asked/answered. The session would just reference the quiz with an session id. Also you may want to destroy the 'Quiz' after the session is complete or keep them for quiz analytics...